# boundedness of norm of convolution

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $1\le p\le \infty$, $f\in L^1(R)$, and $g\in L^p(R)$.
Show that $(f*g)(x)=\int_R f(x-y)g(y)dy$ exists for almost all x, that $f*g\in L^p(R)$, and that $||f*g||_p=||f||_1 ||g||_p$.

So this is from Rudin's RCA 3rd edition chapter 8.

I have proved for $1\le p<\infty$ cases, and I proved that the integral holds for the case $p=\infty$ for almost all x. My question is that how to show $f*g\in L^\infty(R)$ and that its norm is bounded by $||f||_1||g||_\infty$.

Thank you for your answer in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We note that $\left| {u\left( x \right)} \right| \leqslant {\left\| u \right\|_{{L^\infty }}}$ for almost $x\in\mathbb{R}$, for $u\in L^\infty$.

For almost $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we have
$$\begin{gathered}
  \left| {\left( {f * g} \right)\left( x \right)} \right| = \left| {\int_\mathbb{R} {f\left( {x - y} \right)g\left( y \right)dy} } \right| \leqslant \int_\mathbb{R} {\left| {f\left( {x - y} \right)} \right|\left| {g\left( y \right)} \right|dy}  \leqslant \int_\mathbb{R} {\left| {f\left( {x - y} \right)} \right|{{\left\| g \right\|}_{{L^\infty }}}dy}  \hfill \\
   = {\left\| g \right\|_{{L^\infty }}}.\int_\mathbb{R} {\left| {f\left( {x - y} \right)} \right|dy}  = {\left\| g \right\|_{{L^\infty }}}{\left\| f \right\|_{{L^1}}} .\hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$
This implies
$${\left\| {f * g} \right\|_\infty } = \inf \left\{ {M > 0:\left| {\left( {f * g} \right)\left( x \right)} \right| \leqslant M,\,\,\,a.e.\,x \in \mathbb{R}} \right\} \leqslant {\left\| g \right\|_{{L^\infty }}}{\left\| f \right\|_{{L^1}}}.$$